# is LFC shrinkage necessary when using DESEQ differential abundance analysis for microbial abundance data?

Tags: r

LFC shrinkage used to be default in the DESEQ function but it was updated, because it is not always recommended to do. But i cannot find much information on which conditions this is decided.

Are there any conditions I can check first?

Context: I am looking at differential abundance of bacterial ASV's between infected and non-infected samples.

this is my script in R:

```r
deseq_obj = phyloseq_to_deseq2(ps1, ~Microsporidia)
DESeq2_dds = estimateSizeFactors(deseq_obj)
DESeq2_dds = DESeq(DESeq2_dds, fitType="local")
```

shoud i add following line?

```r
res <- lfcShrink(DESeq2_dds, coef=2, type="apeglm")
```